# Zxing QR Code decode function returns null in c#

Tags: c#, decode, zxing, qr-code

I am getting null while using the code below. I am using ZXing dll downloaded from NuGet

```
    using ZXing.Common;
    using ZXing.QrCode;
    using ZXing.QrCode.Internal;

    private void Decode()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"D:\Project\QRCodes\myqrcode.png");
        try
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

            byte[] byteArray = memoryStream.GetBuffer();

            ZXing.LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(byteArray, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
            QRCodeReader qrCodeReader = new QRCodeReader();

            Result str = qrCodeReader.decode(binBitmap);

        }
        catch{ }

    }
```

Please give me a solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: That's the way ZXing.Net works. If no barcode was found it returns "null". Btw. you can use a simpler way. Use the BarcodeReader class with the property PossibleFormats to restrict to QR codes instead of the QRCodeReader. BarcodeReader directly supports Bitmap instances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

problom solved
I got it working by using below code

```
         Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"D:\Project\QRCodes\myqrcode.png");
         try
        {               
            BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader { AutoRotate = true, TryHarder = true };
            Result result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
            string decodedData = result.Text;                
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot decode the QR code");
        }
```

Comment: Normally you should use it that way:
    `Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"D:\Project\QRCodes\myqrcode.png");
    BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader { AutoRotate = true, TryHarder = true };
    Result result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
    if (result == null)
     throw new Exception("Cannot decode the QR code");
    string decodedData = result.Text;`

If ZXing.Net throws an exception than it is a real error. Exceptions are not used to inform the user that no barcode was found.

Comment: this is not work for Nuget Package ZXing Barcode Scanning Library .Net Port v2.1.1 but it is worked with ZXing.Net 0.12.0.0

Comment: For an unknown reason, AutoRotate is required to read string "0061 - Ochoz 16. NP obj. L oční laser" even when it was just encoded to QR Code using the same library and is not rotated. Your code helped me, thank you!